# Make a program use other ports

Tags: port, port-forwarding, ssh-tunnel

My school network is behind a very strict firewall, and I can't connect my e-mail and other programs. Are there any ways to avoid this problem?

Comment: i think tcp forwarding may be relevant. that's like a very basic form of proxy

Answer (score 0):

http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-get-into-blocked-websites-in-school-with-freeproxy/

You need to connect to or set up a proxy that bypasses the security set up at your school. This is a trail and error process and depends on the security set up at your school.

https://www.google.co.za/search?q=proxy+to+avoid+firewall

There are lots of ways to do this, go and have a look.

http://www.raymond.cc/blog/how-to-bypass-most-firewall-and-proxy-restrictions/

Those restrictions were put up for a reason, by passing them may mean that you are violating the terms of use that you / parents signed, which could mean that you could be expelled / suspended etc. Do this at your own risk.

Comment: he probably knows that that is why he tagged his question ssh. he should really state what his problem is with setting up the ssh tunnel